# dataframe transformation python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I am new to pandas. I have dataframe,df with 3 columns:(date),(name) and (count).

Given  each day: is there an easy way to create a new dataframe from original one that contains new columns representing the unique names in the original (name column) and their respective count values in the correct columns?

```
   date        name   count
0  2017-08-07  ABC      12
1  2017-08-08  ABC      5
2  2017-08-08  TTT      6
3  2017-08-09  TAC      5
4  2017-08-09  ABC      10
```

It should now be

```
   date        ABC     TTT    TAC 
0  2017-08-07  12       0      0
1  2017-08-08  5        6      0
3  2017-08-09  10       0      5
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":["2017-08-07","2017-08-08","2017-08-08","2017-08-09","2017-08-09"],"name":["ABC","ABC","TTT","TAC","ABC"], "count":["12","5","6","5","10"]})
df = df.pivot(index='date', columns='name', values='count').reset_index().fillna(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but the representation is still the same as the original dataframe. The intention is to graph each unique names in the('name' column) i.e ABC,TTT and TAC as separate columns with their respective values per day

Comment: You need to save the output of the pivot table to a variable. pivot is not an inplace operation.

Comment: @J. Doe But i tried to plot the dataframe df, but I keep getting a KEY ERROR Here is the code:fig=pyplot.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_title('Plot')
ax.plot(df['ABC' ,'TTT','TAC'] )

Comment: @Bode try `ax.plot(df[['ABC' ,'TTT','TAC']])`